# Prevent current line from being underlined

Tags: themes

I switched from the default theme to wombat and now the current line is highlighted **and** underlined.

With the default theme, it is only highlighted

My init.el file has:

```
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
```

How do I only highlight the current line and **not** underline it while changing themes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `wombat` modifies the `highlight` face (which `hl-line` inherits from), but the theme does not modify `hl-line` itself.  So you'll need to decide which face you actually want to adjust.

Edit the theme:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `custom-theme-visit-theme` <kbd>RET</kbd> `wombat` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Expand the `Highlight` face.
- Edit out the `:underline t`
- Click on "Save Theme"

Or you could leave that face, and *add* theme support for the `hl-line` face:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `custom-theme-visit-theme` <kbd>RET</kbd> `wombat` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Select "Insert Additional Face" and enter `hl-line`
- Expand that and select "Show All Attributes"
- Tick "Underline" and set its value to "Off" if necessary
- Click on "Save Theme"

---

Alternatively, leave the theme and just customize the `highlight` (or `hl-line`) face to ensure underlining is off:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `highlight` <kbd>RET</kbd>

  - or `hl-line`, if you only want to affect that
- Select "Show All Attributes"
- Tick "Underline", set its value to "Off" if necessary, and click "Apply and Save"
- You may wish to *un-tick* other attributes of that face, should they conflict with your theme.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The alternate option is better IMO

Comment: It does depend a bit on your usage.  I found that customizing the `hl-line` face directly (using the alternative/latter method) worked well with this theme, but customizing `highlight` meant the colours clashed badly with the theme -- but removing that colour would affect other themes as well (e.g. no colour highlight at all in the default theme).  There are pros and cons either way.